# getting values from a shortcode with an include

Tags: shortcode, customization

I have a checked a few links but nothing seems to for me in getting the attribute value of a shortcode so that I can use it in a condition.

```
function bf_shortcode_slideshow($atts) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'location' => ''
  ), $atts));

  ob_start();
  if  ( $location = 'home' ) {
  classslider = 'homeslider';
}
  include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/templates/slideshow.php');
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('rotator', 'bf_shortcode_slideshow');
```

In the `slideshow.php` I have a

```
echo 'classslider=' . $classslider;
```

My result for `$classslider` is blank ( nothing is displayed )
Is there another way you should compare `$location` to a string value set  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` changes the scope. You would need to declare `$classslider` global before defining it, and then use `global $classslider;` before using it.

```
function bf_shortcode_slideshow($atts) {
  global $classslider;
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( ...
```

I think that will fix your problem.

I don't understand why you are using `include` at all though. There must be a better way to make that slideshow work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I add `global $classslider` and then echo out $classslider in the included file, I still don't get anything returned. I believe the included file seperate from the shortcode creation is to keep the code clean.

Comment: Did you add `global $classslider;` to the included file as well?

Comment: yes I added it `global $classslider;` at the start of the included file

Comment: Ok In addition so your solution,I made a change in how the condition was written and now it is working.  the condition shouuld have been `if ($location = 'home') {$classslider = "homeslider";}` Thank you

Comment: Explaining exactly what you did might help the next person who wanders by.

Comment: I updated my comment above with the correction on my condition. Tks